# one laravel application for many databases

Tags: php, laravel

hi i have laravel project 
in my server i have this folders

```
project1

project2

project3

project4
```

and they all have same files i just change .env file to connect to the database every project has different database 
and when i change anything on my project i have to upload project file to all folders 
im looking for a way to work with one project and when the user enter project from

```
mywebsite/project1
mywebsite/project2
mywebsite/project3
mywebsite/project4
```

connect him with his database from one source file 
thanks

Comment: DO  you mean each user who logs in has different database? or database differs based on the project user selects?

Comment: every project has his own database

Comment: It think the keyword you're looking is: multi tenancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a multi-tenancy package. One codebase, but separates your assets files, database, etc.

https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant

OR

https://laravel-tenancy.com/

Answer (score 2):

Based on your use case, considering each project selection has different database, you can accomplish this using middleware.

When user selects/changes a project, store it in user's table or in session. Then you can use middleware to switch the database using :

```
\Config::set(...);
 // Refresh config array in connection cache
\DB::purge(...);
// Reconnect
\DB::reconnect(...);
```

However, there is [this](https://github.com/techsemicolon/laravel-dynamic-user-connection) package already available for your needs. Check if it helps